# SSAE 16 SOC II vs ISO/IEC 27001 - Any reason to do both?

Tags: iso27001

I manage risks for a small SaaS provider based in Europe and have always had the understanding that an ISO/IEC 27001 certification covers just about every aspect of information security management and generally holds companies to a higher standard than an SSAE 16 SOC II report (or the European equivalent: ISAE 3402 type 2).

However, from time to time, an American customer will ask about SOC II, suggesting it fulfills some loosely specified requirement that ISO 27001 does not.

Unfortunately, these reports are not widely offered in Europe, and I am not fully convinced it is really worth the effort of hiring an American auditing firm considering the existing ISO 27001 certification.

What additional benefits, if any, may be gained from adding a SOC II report to the mix, within the context of risk management and information security?

Any drawbacks, beyond the obvious elements of cost and hassle? For instance, could the sharing of SOC II reports with customers introduce any additional risk elements?

Comment: Specifically addressing "people ask about SOC II"L: Maybe the people you're talking to specifically need SOC II. Maybe they're not technical and don't know the difference. Maybe they're working off a checklist that corporate handed down, which decrees that every system must be specifically SOC II certified, and omits the possibility of the engineers being more intelligent than the computers they run. It's impossible to know from the outside.

Comment: Of course @Nic, which is why I limited my question to any actual benefits or drawbacks to risk and security management.

Comment: Yup! I wasn't trying to answer your question, just shed light on possible reasons they might specifically care about SOC II.